# How to compare a combo box value with a table value stored in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to compare a `combobox` value with data stored already in database, if data doesn't exist then user should be informed that he should select a record from the list or write down the name which already exist in database!

Below is the code I have written for it:

```
Private Sub btnsave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnsave.Click
    Try
    'Declare new data adapter and new datatable for publisher id & Auhtor id and ISBN
    ' to check record exist already or no
    Dim pda As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim pdt As DataTable
    Dim matchPub_name As String = cboPub_id.Text
    pda = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT pub_name FROM publisher WHERE pub_name =@pub_name", cn)
    pdt = New DataTable
    pda.Fill(pdt)


    Dim ada As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim adt As DataTable
    Dim matchAuthor_name As String = cboAuthor_id.Text
    ada = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT author_name FROM author WHERE author_name =" & matchAuthor_name, cn)
    adt = New DataTable
    ada.Fill(adt)


    Dim matchISBN As String = txtisbn.Text.ToString
    da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT isbn from book WHERE isbn =" & "'" & matchISBN & "'", cn)
    dt = New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)

    If pdt.Rows.Count = -1 Then
        lblAlert.BackColor = Color.HotPink
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(cboPub_id, _
                                "*Please Select or type available Publishers or register new in Publisher form")
        lblAlert.Text = "Check Respected Error"
        lblInfo.Text = ""
    ElseIf adt.Rows.Count = -1 Then
        lblAlert.BackColor = Color.HotPink
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(cboAuthor_id, _
                                "*Please Select or type available Authors or register new in Author form")
        lblAlert.Text = "Check Respected Error"
        lblInfo.Text = ""
    ElseIf dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        lblAlert.BackColor = Color.HotPink
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(cboAuthor_id, _
                                "*a record with provided ISBN already exist in Database. Insert Unique ISBN")
        lblAlert.Text = "Check Respected Error"
        lblInfo.Text = ""
    Else
        'Insert into Book Table
        cmd = New SqlCommand("Insert into book(isbn, book_name, price, rack_no, no_of_books, staff_id, " _
                             & " pub_id, sub_code, author_id) values(@isbn, @book_name, @price, @rack_no, " _
                             & " @no_of_books, @staff_id, @pub_id, @sub_code, @author_id)", cn)
        With cmd.Parameters
            .AddWithValue("@isbn", txtisbn.Text).ToString()
            .AddWithValue("@book_name", txtbook_name.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@price", txtprice.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@rack_no", txtrack_no.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@no_of_books", TxtNo_of_Books.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@staff_id", Convert.ToInt32(cboStaff_id.SelectedValue.ToString()))
            .AddWithValue("@pub_id", Convert.ToInt32(cboPub_id.SelectedValue.ToString()))
            .AddWithValue("@sub_code", cboSub_Code.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@author_id", cboAuthor_id.SelectedValue)
        End With
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        'Insert into Published_by Table
        cmd = New SqlCommand("Insert into published_by(isbn, pub_id, pub_date, vol_no) " _
                             & " values(@isbn, @pub_id, @pub_date, @vol_no)", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isbn", txtisbn.Text).ToString()
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pub_id", Convert.ToInt32(cboPub_id.SelectedValue.ToString()))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pub_date", DateTimePicker1.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vol_no", txtvol_no.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        'Insert into Authored_by Table
        cmd = New SqlCommand("Insert into authored_by(isbn, author_id, completion_date) " _
                             & " values(@isbn, @author_id, @completion_date)", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isbn", txtisbn.Text).ToString()
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@author_id", cboAuthor_id.SelectedValue)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@completion_date", dtpCompletion_Date.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        'MessageBox.Show("Record Saved Successfully", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        lblAlert.Text = ""
        lblInfo.Text = "Saved"
    End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Not Completed Because OF The Following Error " & "%" & ex.Message & "%", "Error", _
    '              MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
```

but when I am entering data in `cboAuthor_Name` which is not available in DB it gives error `Invalid column name ' '`

how to handle this? any help?

Comment: a) dont concat SQL ever - use SQL Parameters always.  b) cboAuthor_Name isnt referenced there, not sure how that code relates to the problem

Comment: A few clarification: pub_name is a column of type text? and you declare a variable dt but fill a pdt. Is it a typo?

Comment: @Steve yes it was a typo just edited it and yes pub_name is text

Comment: @Plutonix then how to compare I don't want the user get the message: `primary key violation` blah blah!!!

Comment: I dont follow, what does a PK violation have to do with SQL params or asking for clarification on the code?

Comment: Oh no @Plutonix I didn't commented on your comment I just said how to handle user entry to only value that already exist in the DB !!!

Comment: Why do you have to run a SELECT query to see if the publisher name exists?  If the name is not in the CBO isnt that the same thing?  Even then, I'd think a *persistent* dt of publishers might be worth having.  Use it to fill teh CBO and check for exists and add.

Comment: ... *thats* what I was asking - the original form of the question did not include anything for author but the text describes `cboAuthor_Name` being central to the problem.

Comment: @Plutonix I think steve is offline I need your little help please!!!

Comment: @Plutonix  for ISBN I do not need to check for nothing but I want to check that if user enters duplicate pk(ISBN is pk) then he should be informed that ISBN already exist??? how to achieve this in the format of answer that steve shared also when I `Dim authorName = cmdd.ExecuteScalar()
                ElseIf authorName Is Nothing Then` go like this compiler give error that authorName is not declared although it is as you can see it!!! how solve these two issues?

Comment: I still dont understand how `cboAuthor_Name` factors into anything - it is not mentioned in the code anywhere, yet is the posted question.  Also, those If/Else If Row count tests are not mutually exclusive

Comment: ...Steve's `authorname` is declared inside that Using block which creates a local scope.  If you (or he) tried to use it outside that block you will get a compiler error.  Hard to say since I cant see where/how you are trying to use it.  Some of these seems unnecessary though.  If the CBO is a list of all publishers, why do you need to hit the db at all? not in cbo == not in db, right?

Comment: @Plutonix yes actually my code was working fine to select one value at a time from cbo but suppose if the list gets increased like 100 list items! then for this reason I also enabled cbo for data entry but only that data which is already there in the database!

Comment: Sorry, but you are doing everything the hardest way possible.  For instance with Publisher, you could have a persistent DataAdapter (and DT and CommandBuilder).  You can set these up so they know how to read and SAVE to the database.  So the datasource for the CBO would be the dtPub.  If it is not in the DT (==not in CBO) then it is new.  When you add a new publisher, you add the data to the DT and `daPub.Update(dtPub)` adds all the new rows AND updates any changed rows. One small line of code.  I'd be horrified by all that code in a click event.  Managing base tbls is just not that grueling.

Comment: thank you for the idea and all these explanations I am very new I will try to apply these points slowly and gradually across all my projects! :) @Plutonix

Comment: Read the page on SQLDataAdapter at MSDN.  They can be "taught" how to Update and Insert into the table.  If you keep it hanging around (like in a Publisher Class) to add a row just add a row to the DataTable and Update it.  The DA knows which rows to add, which to update.  Then you can create Views from the DT for searches, CBOs etc etc.  You can easily query the DT to see if a Publisher or ISBN exits without volumes of SQL littering every click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems in your code. The worst one is the string concatenation to build an sql query. Then there is a lesser one in using an SqlDataAdapter filling a DataTable only to discover if a record exists or not.

You could change your code to

```
Private Sub btnsave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnsave.Click

    Dim matchPub_name As String = cboPub_name.Text
    Dim matchAuthor_name As String = cboAuthor_id.Text
    Dim matchISBN As String = txtisbn.Text.ToString

    Using conn = new SqlConnection(....constring here ....)
    Using cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT pub_name FROM publisher WHERE pub_name = @name", conn)
        conn.Open
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = matchPub_name
        Dim publisherName = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        if publisherName is Nothing Then
              lblAlert.BackColor = Color.HotPink
              ErrorProvider1.SetError(cboPub_name, _
                                "*Please Select .....")
              lblAlert.Text = "Check Respected Error"
              lblInfo.Text = ""
              Return
        End If

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT author_name FROM author WHERE author_name = @name"
        cmd.Parameters("@name").Value = matchAuthor_name
        Dim authorName = cmd.ExecuteScalar() 
        if authorName is Nothing Then
            lblAlert.BackColor = Color.HotPink
            ErrorProvider1.SetError(cboAuthor_name, _
                                "*Please Select .....")
            lblAlert.Text = "Check Respected Error"
            lblInfo.Text = ""
            Return
        End If
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT isbn from book WHERE isbn = @name"
        cmd.Parameters("@name").Value = matchISBN 
        Dim isbnCode = cmd.ExecuteScalar() 
        if isbnCode IsNot Nothing Then
            lblAlert.BackColor = Color.HotPink
            ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtISBN, _
                                "*ISBN Exists .....")
            lblAlert.Text = "Check Respected Error"
            lblInfo.Text = ""
            Return
        End If
        ' Now insert into Book Table '
    End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Using parameters is the correct way to pass values to your database instead of building a text that is subject to parsing problems (your original code misses the single quote around the name) and Sql Injection attacks. Using directly a command with ExecuteScalar doesn't require to build a datatable. ExecuteScalar returns the first column of the first row, if any, otherwise the return is nothing.
Notice also that I don't use a global connection object but build one on the spot and destroy it through the Using block. There is a mechanism called Connection Pooling that allow objects like a Connection to be rebuilt very easily and quickly.

Comment: Steve can I add more `if conditions`? in here I just posted a snap of my code, actually I have one author combobox to check it same like publisher name and also I need to compare table pk(ISBN) that it should not be a duplicate value and if all these succeeded then I want that my record should be save!

Comment: If you need to check two different tables then you need two different sql commands. So if you have also an author table (and you need to check if the author exists) and if you have a book table to check if the ISBN exists then you need to look for every table. Or perhaps you should provide your user interface with fixed choices. Not allowing to choose from your combobox something that doesn't exists (IE.ComboBoxStyle. DropDownList instead of DropDown)

Comment: but if I select DropDownList and there is more data in the list how is the user going to look for all that data ? That's why I changed style to Dropdown so either the user should select an item from the list or type it!

Comment: Then you need to add your checks before inserting the new record. You could write a stored procedure that makes all the checks in a single call but in any case you need a try/catch around the insert to be sure of catching errors at the moment of the insert)

Comment: Steve please check I have updated the question how achieve the points to mentioned in the above scenario ?

Comment: Steve for ISBN I do no need to check for nothing but I want to check that if user enters duplicate pk(ISBN is pk) then he should be informed that ISBN already exist???

Comment: Answer updated with a proper if/then after each test on the db values.

Answer (score 0):

```
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Addbookdetails", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@class", ddlclass.SelectedValue.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Booktype", txtbktype.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", Convert.ToInt32(txtqty.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", Convert.ToInt32(txtPrice.Text));
```